# How do we implement filtering on columns in a table in rdlc?

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to filter two columns in my report. I used the in-built tablix properties to apply filters to the columns but it was of no use. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: please, can you explain what type of filter would you apply to column of tablix?

Comment: I want to implement a dropdown list with options from a column of the table. Hence when the user chooses a option, all records with that option will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS provides the capability to define a dataset to be used to populate the dropdown list for a report parameter.  When you define the dataset you specify a query or stored procedure that will return the list of values for the report parameter dropdown.

Example:

1. Create a new dataset that will be used to populate the first report parameter dropdown list

[image]

2. Configure Report Parameters

   - Select the paramenter to fill in the Parameters listbox and specify the Available values as shown below

   [image]